# Using XML::Twig locally without installing in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, porting

I've written a relatively large script in Perl. A part of it should now be able to manipulate XML data. As far as I know XML::Twig would be the appropriate module for this kind of operation. Since the finished program does not run on my machine and I'm not able to install extra packages on the target system, I've decided to use XML::Twig locally. Hence I've copied it in a subfolder of my script, loaded it with `use lib "$FindBin::Bin/foreign/";` (the `Twig.pm` was found there under the path `foreign/XML/Twig.pm`) and `use XML::Twig;`.

On my Windows 7 Machine it worked perfectly. Now I've tried it on a Linux environment (Ubuntu), which is desired later, with the following error:

> Can't locate loadable object for module XML::Parser::Expat in @INC

I really don't want to write my own library and I'm not able to install extra packages on this system (but it should work under those circumstances). Every suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: "I'm not able to install extra packages on this system" is not true. If you can install code from SO, you can install code from CPAN.

Comment: CPAN won't find a mirror because the ports are blocked from the admin

Comment: CPAN is blocked but not SO? I can copy the file over here if you want.

Comment: sorry, I don't know what you mean with "SO" ?

Comment: This site, StackOverflow

Comment: ok, to be honest I'm not sure why... but I can't even install additional packages via `apt-get` and CPAN is not able to find any mirrors... which file should I look at?

Comment: The "download" link from the page I linked in my answer. (Don't get the developer release.) Weren't you just there to read the README file???

Answer (score 1):

Bits of XML::Parser::Expat are missing. Reinstall it.

It's part of the [XML-Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Parser/) distribution on CPAN. Follow the instructions in the README file.

Comment: How? Please remember, something like `sudo apt-get install ...` is not an option.

Comment: If you can't install the libraries you depend on, rewrite your code to not use those libraries.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to avoid writing an XML parser from scratch... therefore I wanted to check if there are other possibilities

Comment: To follow the instructions I need to install it via `perl Makefile.PL` for which I don't have enough user rights

Comment: Good thing, cause you shouldn't be messing with the system Perl. Now read the line after the one where you stopped reading.

Comment: In case that wasn't clear, the line below the one that suggests `perl Makefile.PL` suggests an alternative usage that allows you to specify where you want to install the files. `perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=~/perl5 LIB=~/perl5/lib` is what I used before I started using `perlbrew`.

Answer (score 1):

You need not only XML::Twig copied locally, but every other non-core module used by Twig (and used by the modules that are used by Twig, etc.).

One reason why it might work on your PC is that you have XML::Parser::Expat installed on that PC, but it's not on the Linux box.  Include this (and all other dependent modules) in your "foreign" folder, and you can create a "portable" version of you script+modules.

To answer the op's follow-up comment to this initial post, XML::Parser::Expat is NOT part of XML::Parser, it's separate.  See this section from the beginning of my copy of XML::Parser:

```
BEGIN {
  require XML::Parser::Expat;
  $VERSION = '2.41';
  die "Parser.pm and Expat.pm versions don't match"
    unless $VERSION eq $XML::Parser::Expat::VERSION;
}
```

Comment: I've already added the `XML::Parser` module into the path, but it does not change anything... if I'm right, this should be the module containing `XML::Parser::Expat`?

Comment: See the 2nd part of my post.  It's a separate module/file.

Comment: I understand, but I can not find a download link or something... always as part of XML::Parser, e.g.: http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/XML-Parser-2.41/Expat/Expat.pm

Comment: If you copy Expat.pm to "foreign/XML/Parser/Expat.pm", doesn't that work?  If not, please share the exact current contents of your your "foreign" folder tree, and the error you're getting now.  Might be easier to do this my editing your post than trying to add to a comment here.

Comment: Your diagnosis is incorrect. That message can only occur if some of XML::Parser::Expat is installed.

Comment: Your solution is incorrect. Copying Expat.pm won't work. In fact, that's probably what the OP do to get that error. This is the worse advise!

Comment: XML::Parser::Expat is part of XML-Parser, XML::Parser's distribution.

Comment: @ikegami, yes Expat is part of the distribution, but XML::Parser::Expat (the module) is NOT part of XML::Parser (the file).  He has to copy more than Parser.pm, he has to copy at least Parser/Expat.pm, and possibly more under the Parser folder.  And I didn't say this was the *best* advice (I agree with installing modules correctly on each system, or at least in a central place that the systems can reach).  But, this is the problem facing the op, and I'm trying to help.

Comment: Again, he has XML/Parser/Expat.pm. He doesn't have XML/Parser/Expat.so. Re "I'm trying to help", I don't doubt your motives.

Comment: There's a compiled piece to Expat?  Hadn't noticed that.  @beyeran, there's no way to copy just the text file for a module that has compiled code.  You might (?) be able to copy the .SO file between identical systems, but I don't believe it will work between Windows and Linux.

Comment: @jimtut, yes, it has a dynamically **loadable object**. That would be a prerequisite for not being able to find it... And you're right about copying the .dll from Windows not working.